# Evaluating $\iiint_R\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\right)\,dx\,dy\,dz$ given the region $R$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\iiint_R\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\right)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$, where $R$ is the region bounded by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=1-x^2-y^2$.

Here is what I did:

Let: $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $z=z$.

First, consider $z=x^2+y^2$.

$r\in(0,\frac{\sqrt2}{2})$, $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$, $z\in(r^2,\frac{1}{2})$

$$\iiint\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\right)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{r^2}^{\frac{1}{2}}r(1-\cos\theta)\,dz\,d\theta\, dr=\frac{\pi}{8}$$
Then consider $z=1-x^2-y^2$
For $r\in(0,\frac{\sqrt2}{2})$, $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$, $z\in(1-r^2,1)$  $$\iiint\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\right)\,dx\,dy\,dz=\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1-r^2}^{1}r(1-\cos\theta)\,dz\,d\theta\, dr=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

For the final answer I added those up and I got $\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{8}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, you are correct. I've fixed those errors and completed my post.

Comment: Why do you get those limits for z? See my comment below for a walkthrough.

Answer (score 3):

Your subsitution is fine, cylindrical coordinates. But you messed up with the limits. Obviously $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ . We have that z goes from the bottom surface to the top one, so you have to first identify them.  In this case $z=r^2$ is the one below and $z=1-r^2$ the one above, so $z \in (r^2,1-r^2)$. Then we have to define the limits for the radius. The radius goes from $0$ to the interception between both surfaces:

$$ r^2=1-r^2 \Rightarrow r=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \text{     ,because  }r>0  $$

Considering the jacobian is $r$, the integral becomes:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \int_{r^2}^{1-r^2} (1-\cos{\theta})\space r \space dz\space dr \space d\theta $$

The cosine part is $0$ because of the symmetry, and then we have that:

$$ \text{Integral} =2\pi \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} (1-2r^2) \space rdr = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Should there be an extra r in the integral when you switch the x,y,z plane to the polar coordinates? Since the determinant of the Jaccobian matrix is r.

Comment: By the way, I completed my answer. Could you point out which part I did wrong?

Comment: You are right! I just fixed it. You are mistaking in the limits of z. in cilyndrical coordinates, z is the height, so it goes from the floor to the ceil of the function. Note that here the floor is the surface $z=x^2+y^2=r^2$ and the roof is $z=1-(x^2+y^2)=1-r^2$, hence those limits. I don´t know where did you get those limits.